# Calling IDX MLS SOAP APIs of ihomefinder from Java Spring MVC

Tags: java, maven, spring-mvc, soap, wsdl

I want to use ihomefinder's test APIs to get the data and insert it into my own database. I am using Spring MVC and the link provided by them which I configured in my pom.xml to get the data is http://axisws.idxre.com:8080/axis2/services/IHFPartnerServices?wsdl.
From various searches I found that all the provided APIs are in package `com.ihomefinder.api` so I included it too into the pom.xml

Here is the pom.xml code:

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-ws</artifactId>
        <version>1.3.1.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.jvnet.jaxb2.maven2</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-jaxb2-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>0.13.1</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>generate</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
            <configuration>
                <schemaLanguage>WSDL</schemaLanguage>
                <generatePackage>com.ihomefinder.api</generatePackage>
                <schemas>
                    <schema>
                        <url>http://axisws.idxre.com:8080/axis2/services/IHFPartnerServices?wsdl</url>
                    </schema>
                </schemas>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Now I am trying to login with the test username and password provided by them, but to hit the login service I need to create the Object of Request class which is not found in the package `com.ihomefinder.api`.

Here is the java code I am using to make the request:

```
import javax.xml.bind.JAXBElement;    
import org.springframework.ws.client.core.support.WebServiceGatewaySupport;
import org.springframework.ws.soap.client.core.SoapActionCallback;
import com.ihomefinder.api.Login;
import com.ihomefinder.api.ObjectFactory;

public class IdxMls extends WebServiceGatewaySupport {

    public void main() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        ObjectFactory objectFactory = new ObjectFactory();
        JAXBElement<String> user = objectFactory.createLoginUsername("username");
        JAXBElement<String> pass = objectFactory.createLoginPassword("password");
        Login login = new Login();
        login.setUsername(user);
        login.setPassword(pass);        
        Integer int1 = (Integer) getWebServiceTemplate().marshalSendAndReceive(login, new SoapActionCallback("http://axisws.idxre.com:8080/axis2/services/Login"));
        System.out.println(int1);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        IdxMls idxMls = new IdxMls();
        idxMls.main();
    }

}
```

I think the above code is not perfect some things are really missing. So can anybody help me to correct the code by which I can get the response from the API?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're using our partner API soap client. Our most current Reseller API is a REST API, and the entry point URL is:

https://www.idxhome.com/restServices/reseller/login

Documentation for the reseller API is not publicly posted at this time. Please email us at support@ihomefinder.com, and we would be happy to provide you the documentation.